# Python: print replace comma to dot

Tags: python

I don't know how it works and can't see answer for this.  I wanted to replace comma to dot in file. So i write this code:

```
with fileinput.FileInput("tabela.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace(',', '.')
```

and i thought it should work. But it didn't. But when i replace line=line.replace(...) to:

```
    print(line.replace(",", "."), end='')
```

it works fine. Can someone explain why line=line.replace(...) doesn't work but print(...) which should just print something (and it even doesn't print lines) replace my comma to dots?
Thanks for answers

EDIT: I said that print should just print something, but ofc it's not true (i think) because as I can see it replace strings in my file in some reason with replace function.

Comment: The Python standard library really is quite massive. I've been using Python for years and only just learned about the `fileinput` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)

> **Optional in-place filtering:** if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently).

So the library is built with the use-case of "get input in a variable and output to standard out" in mind. Hence, `print` is the intended mechanism.

Simply assigning to a local variable and then discarding the result does nothing. It replaces the string in memory and then... garbage collects it soon after. The real-world analogy would be doing a bunch of math homework on a sheet of paper and then putting the paper in the trash rather than submitting it; my teacher isn't going to grade what I throw away.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense, thanks a lot, I missed that in docs.